# NUnit 3.0 以降の nunit.exe について

Tags: c#, .net

最近では Visual Studio 2015 のテストエクスプローラーから、NUnit 3 を利用したユニットテストを行っているのですが、VisualStudioがインストールされていない環境で、GUIからテスト実行しようとした所、http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=download で配布されているNUnit-3.*.zip にnunit.exeが見つからず、どうしたものかと悩まされました。

VisualStudioがインストールされていない環境の場合、NUnit 3.0 以上をテストするにはどうしたら良いのでしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

コマンドラインから`nunit3-console.exe`でテストを実行するか、[nunit-gui](https://github.com/nunit/nunit-gui)を自分でビルドして使用することになります。